# Application level errors

Tags: android, error-handling

Is there any way to catch the application errors for all activities? For example, in the Application level. Something like

```
public class MyApp extends Application { ... catch error ... }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to register an exception handler that will be triggered when an exception occurs anywhere that you do not handle locally.

Comment: Can I use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() in the Application class or in each activity?

Comment: @PlanComunicacion: You typically only need to call it once. You are welcome to do so from an `Application`, or from a static initializer, or wherever makes sense.